# JavaFX| TableView not populating some fields

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a TableView and getters and setters from my data class. All of the fields are populated except for one. I have looked through my code and I can't tell why. May someone aid me please?

I have a conditional statement to say that if the data isn't found, show N/A on the table. The table shows N/A on all rows but if I output the value of this field on the console, it shows me that there is something present.

```
//populating my tableview...
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
      ConcreteObservable concreteObservable = new ConcreteObservable();   patientsTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(concreteObservable.getPatients()));
        for (int i = 0; i < ConcreteObservable.PATIENTSLIST.size(); i++) {
            /*fields that are successfully populated are here, I removed them for space but I used the same 
format in the cholesterolCol, just changed columnName and data field name and it still wont work */
            cholesterolCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("currentCholesterolLevel"));
            dateRecordedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateRecorded"));
        }
    }
```

This is my data class

```
public class ConcreteObservable implements IObservable {
      private String currentCholesterolLevel;

//method that sets the values of my data
public List<ConcreteObservable> getPatients(){
if (observation.getCode().getText().equals("Total Cholesterol")) {
  currentCholesterolLevel = observation.getValueQuantity().getValue().toString();
  setCurrentCholesterolLevel(currentCholesterolLevel);

//tried to do it this way incase the line above did not work
myPatient.setCurrentCholesterolLevel(currentCholesterolLevel);
         myPatient.setDateRecorded(dateRecorded);
        } else {
                 myPatient.setCurrentCholesterolLevel("N/A");
                 myPatient.setDateRecorded("No Cholesterol Recording");
                    }
return PATIENTSLIST;

                }

    public void setCurrentCholesterolLevel(String currentCholesterolLevel) {
             this.currentCholesterolLevel = currentCholesterolLevel;
         }

    public String getCurrentCholesterolLevel() {
                    return currentCholesterolLevel;
                }
}
```

My tableview only populates the N/A. I tried `JOPtionPane.showMessageDialog()` and it does show me the actual cholesterol values, so why can I not set them so I can read them from the table if they exist?

Comment: _Unrelated: As you're using JavaFX, you should use `javafx.scene.control.Alert` instead of Swing's `JOptionPane`._

Comment: Hmm, I think I would have the cell handle displaying `N/A`, or maybe even the value factory, instead of setting `N/A` on the model item.  Regardless, could you create a [mcve] and then [edit] your question to add it, please? It's hard to know what's wrong without seeing the full (but _minimal_) picture.

Comment: Are you sure `observation.getCode().getText()` yields `"Total Cholesterol"`? Furthermore where is the `return` statement in `getPatients`. Also why do you set the `cellValueFactory`s once per element in `ConcreteObservable.PATIENTSLIST` (which you also don't provide any info about)?

Comment: I am sure `observation.getCode().getText()` yields `"Total Cholesterol"`. That was the first thing I checked by outputting the value of `observation.getValueQuantity().getValue().toString()` in the console - my problem is getting this value to show in the table (everything else displays correctly).  With regards to the `return` statement in `getPatients()`, I must have removed it as when I was minimising the code, it is there though, i'll edit the post. I don't understand what you're asking in the last bit though, clarity please?